# Shortcut to implementing every single rich ordering method in a Python class individually?

Tags: python, class, oop, magic-methods

I have a Python class that I'd like to support [rich ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) by one of its attributes. I could of course simply implement all the magic ordering methods like `__lt__`, `__le__` etc. with that attribute as the key, but that seems a bit cumbersome and repetetive. Is there a way I can simply define that attribute as the ordering key once and have Python figure out the individual comparisons automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Python3.2 or later, you can use [functools.total_ordering](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering).

> Given a class defining one or more rich comparison ordering methods,
>   this class decorator supplies the rest. This simplifies the effort
>   involved in specifying all of the possible rich comparison operations:
>
> The class must define one of __ lt__(), __ le__(), __ gt__(), or
>   __ ge__(). In addition, the class should supply an __ eq__() method.

Comment: Ah, I new that Python wouldn't let me down:) Thank you!